# How to find the basis $U=\{p∈P_3\mid p(3)=0\}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

So, I need to prove $U=\{p∈P_3\mid p(3)=0\}$ is a subspace of $P_3$ and I had no trouble doing so since:

$p(3)$ is the zero vector.

$p(3)$ adding $q(3)$ is just $0$ as well since we defined $p(3)=0$.

Any scalar multiplication of $p(3)$ is just multiplication of $0$.

However, I am unsure how to find the basis of it. I do propose $x^2-3x$ being the basis for the subspace but is that correct? Or is there more functions in the basis?

Comment: It is a three dimensional  space. One vector cannot form  a basis. Look at $(x-3),(x-3)^{2}, (x-3)^{3}$ instead.

Comment: Curly brackets `{  }` are special in MathJax. So if you want to actually have curly brackets in your math expressions, you need to tell MathJax that these brackets _aren't_ special. This is done by typing `\{  \}`.

Comment: $p(3)$ isn't the zero vector. $p(3)$ isn't a polynomial, and isn't an element of $P_3$. You want to show that whatever the zero vector of the vector space $P_3$ is, that vector is also contained in $U$. The value of a polynomial at $3$ is not that.

Comment: As an alternative, note that every degree-at-most-3 polynomial can be written in the form $(x-3)(ax^2+bx+c)+d$.  This should be easy to prove (*quotient-remainder theorem*).  This observation leads to recognizing that the condition $p(3)=0$ is equivalent to $d=0$ and leads to another choice of basis being $\{(x-3),x(x-3),x^2(x-3)\}$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

\begin{align*}
P(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3\in U&\iff a_0+3a_1+9a_2+27a_3=0\\
&\iff P(x)=a_1(x-3)+a_2(x^2-9)+a_3(x^3-27).
\end{align*}

I let you conclude.